# Call exe from javascript

Tags: javascript, call

I noted that some sites like this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
(click on install)

can call external program prompting a request.

I remember the use of ActiveXObject years ago but now it is not supported in my chrome browser.

How can these sites call external program with javascript?
Is it possible to call a program without the prompt?

Comment: That is a VSCode extension, what does it have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: The site in the link call vscode exe if you click on "Install". I guess that the site uses javascript.

Comment: So you are talking about when you click install it is prompted VSCode to install it. Custom Url Scheme

Comment: I don't know about Url Scheme. How it works? Where can I find information to write a web page that call exe with Url Scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the button to install the plugin, it is calling `vscode:extension/streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker`

It is using a registered [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) which your application is able to handle. [How to register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) it really depends on what your application is written in.

Comment: The javascript can comunicate with the .exe? Can javascript call it without prompt?